# how to mongoose delete cascade in latest version of mongoose without model.remove()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Not able to delete cascade as Model.remove() fuction is not available in mongoose.
using findByIdAndDelete is not invoking the middleware:

```
BootcampSchema.pre('remove',async function(next){  //before deleting the doc
    console.log(`courses being removed from bootcamp ${this._id}`);
    await this.model('Course').deleteMany({bootcamp:this._id});
    next();
});
```

tried different delete methods but can't delete cascade

Answer (score 0):

This code is from Bootcamp model, I accidentally named it with C capital in Camp so if you named it Bootcamp just replace it in with your naming convention.

```
BootCampSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true }, async function(next) {
  console.log(`Courses being removed from bootcamp ${this._id}`);
  await this.model('Course').deleteMany({ bootcamp: this._id });
  next();
});
```

This code is from bootcamp controler

```
exports.deleteBootcamp = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!bootcamp) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Bootcamp with id of ${req.params.id} not found`, 404));
  }

  await bootcamp.deleteOne();
  await Course.deleteMany( { bootcamp: bootcamp._id });

  res.status(200).json({ 
    success: true, 
    data: {} 
  })
});
```

This works perfectly for me, so I hope it'll work for others as well.